# PHP mysqli_connect: I'm getting this error when my login page attempt to connect to the database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to my sqli the improved version of PHP.

```
<?php

// Class for the transparent access of MySQL

$con = mysqli_connect("host","database","port","user","passwd","conn","querytext","query_id","err","errno","record = array();","row = 0;","rows = 0;") or die ("Some error occured during connection " . mysqli_error($con));

        function query($querystring) {
                $this->querytext = $querystring;
                $this->query_id = mysqli_query($this->querytext, $this->con);
                $this->Errno = mysqli_errno($this->conn);
                $this->Error = mysqli_error($this->conn);
                if($this->query_id) {
           if(strtolower(substr(trim($this->querytext),0,6)) == 'select'){
                        $this->rows = mysqli_num_rows($this->query_id);
                   } else {
                        $this->rows = 0;
           }
                        $this->row = 0;
                } else {
                        $this->rows = 0;
                        $this->row = 0;
                        $this->halt("Query failed!");
                }
        }

        function setpassword($newpasswd){
           $querystring = sprintf("SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('%s')", $newpasswd1);
           return $this->query($querystring);
        }

        function next_record() {
                if($this->row < $this->rows) {
                        $this->record = mysql_fetch_array($this->query_id);
                $this->Errno = mysql_errno($this->conn);
                $this->Error = mysql_error($this->conn);
                        $this->row +=1;
                        $status = is_array($this->record);
                } else {
                        $status = FALSE;
                }
                return $status;
        }


        function seek($pos) {
                if(($pos >= 0 && $pos < $this->rows) &&
                   mysql_data_seek($this->query_id, $pos)) {
               $this->Errno = mysql_errno($this->conn);
               $this->Error = mysql_error($this->conn);
                       $this->row = $pos;
                }
        }


        function close() {
                $this->query = "";
                $this->rows = 0;
                $this->row = 0;
                mysql_close($this->conn);
        }

        function htmltable () {
                $resulttable='';
                if($this->rows > 0){
                        $resulttable=sprintf("<table %s>", $tableoptions);
                        while($this->next_record()) {
                                /* Ueberschriften */
                                if($this->row == 1) {
                                        $resulttable=$resulttable . "<tr>";
                                        while(list($key, $value)=each($this->record)){
                                                $resulttable=$resulttable . "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
                                        }
                                $resulttable=$resulttable . "</tr>\n";
                                reset($this->record);
                                } /* Ende Ueberschriften */
                                $resulttable=$resulttable . "<tr>";
                                while(list($key, $value)=each($this->record)){
                                        $resulttable=$resulttable . "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
                                }
                                $resulttable=$resulttable . "</tr>\n";
                        }
                        $resulttable=$resulttable . "</table>\n";
                }
                return $resulttable;
        }



?>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Good Lord, does `mysqli_connect()` even take that many arguments? *lol!*

Comment: `$this->query_id = mysqli_query($this->querytext, $this->con);` well that is definitely failing. The connection comes first in mysqli_, not 2nd.

Comment: You're mixing mysql and mysqli. Don't use any functions that start with `mysql_`, they are deprecated.

Comment: There are far too many errors made here. Best you go back and RTM's.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner that was my first intent too.... and even if it does... guess using it like this is Horrible

Comment: @AbraCadaver of paper, right? ah but what kind of paper?? haha!!

Comment: @Dwza Horrible, that you would be correct ;-)

Comment: `$this->record = mysql_fetch_array($this->query_id);` ah yes; mixing different apis. Well, this isn't vegetable soup we're making here.

Comment: http://codular.com/php-mysqli this is the only thing that might help yo right now (one of a million) :D

Comment: I'm also laughing at myself but this is a huge project I think it will be best if you come to the rescue you help. the error is "Some error occured during connection

Comment: That's your error.  You need to use `mysqli_connect_error()` and also `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`.

Comment: thanks Abra il dig for more solutions

Answer (score 0):

You should be connecting to the database using PDO as it is more secure: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

These tutorials are pretty good to follow: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers 
http://crewow.com/PHP-MySQL-Simple-Select-using-PDO-in-Bootstrap.php

Also, please make sure that your database credentials are in a separate file that gets included into the file you use to connect to the database.

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking the turorials @Goerge

Comment: Can I please get assistant on the function query.

Comment: I need help on the query function. I haven't yet defined my code well